# How Messagebox Show connecting to the url link

Tags: vb.net, dialog, messagebox

I want to add a link, when the message appears, there is an ok button, when they click it will lead to the target URL link, how do I do it, can you help me

```
Public Shared Sub NewsInfo()
    MessageBox.Show("this message will appear")
End Sub
```

I have tried but error

```
If MessageBox.Show(Program."Demo version", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
    New Process() With { .StartInfo = { .FileName = "http://www.google.com" } }.Start()             
End If
```

Comment: You don't. The `MessageBox` class just displays a message. If you want more than that, you need to create your own form and display that. Internally, `MessageBox.Show` just creates a form with the appropriate controls, calls `ShowDialog` on it and then returns the appropriate `DialogResult`. You can do the same with your own form.

Comment: can you give an example of how to do it ?? I have tried but error

`If MessageBox.Show(Program."Demo version", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
    New Process() With { .StartInfo = { .FileName = "http://www.google.com" } }.Start()

   End If`

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. I thought you were saying that you wanted to actually display a hyperlink that the user could click. If you're just saying that you want to open a URL then just open a URL. That's not a "link".

Comment: As for the issue, you say that you get an error but you don't tell us what the error message is or exactly where it occurs. That is never acceptable. That's always relevant information. That said, this part looks nonsensical: `Program."Demo version"`. What exactly are you trying to achieve there? What is `Program` and what do you think `."Demo version"` should do there?

Comment: If you want to open a URL in the default browser, just call `Process.Start(url)`. Anything else is complicating things unnecessarily. I doubt that has anything to do with your issue though, as indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help

```
if (MessageBox.Show(
        "test", "Visit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk
    ) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**